# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'connect'). Twilio SDK Javascript with Django

Tags: django, twilio, twilio-api, voice

Im developing a Dialer web app with Django and to make calls trought the browser im user Twilio SDK and Im reciving this error

Complete error:

```
ContentDispatcherService: no listeners for an event TAB_STATE__GET_NAVIGATION_METHOD
caller:1  Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
caller.js:20 Requesting Access Token...
caller.js:87  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'connect')
    at start_device (caller.js:87:12)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (caller:75:86)
caller.js:52 Device registered
```

So im trying to make a call trhoug connect(); method but it doesnt stablish the conection, the device is register and idk what means on it.

script

```
/


async function start_device() {
    console.log("Requesting Access Token...");
    /*Document ready*/
    $.get('token', { forPage: window.location.pathname })
        .then(function (data) {
            
            device = new Twilio.Device(data.token,
                {
                    codecPreferences: ["opus", "pcmu"],
                    fakeLocalDTMF: true,
                    enableRingingState: true
                });
            
            device.on("ready", function (device) {
                console.log("Twilio.Ready");
                updateCallStatus("Ready");
            });

            device.on('registered',function(reg){
                console.log('Device registered');
                updateCallStatus('Registered');
            });

            device.on("error", function (error) {
                console.log("Twilio.Device Error: " + error.message);
                updateCallStatus("ERROR: " + error.message);
            });

            device.on("connect", function (conn) {
                // Enable the hang up button and disable the call buttons
                hangUpButton.prop("disabled", false);

                updateCallStatus("Calling");
            });


            device.on("disconnect", function (conn) {
                // Disable the hangup button and enable the call buttons
                hangUpButton.prop("disabled", true);


                updateCallStatus("Ready");
            });

            device.register();

            startDevice.prop('disabled', true)

        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
            console.log("Could not get a token from server!");
        });

    var call = await device.connect({ 
        params: {
          To: '+15551234567'
        } 
      });
}
```

I tried creating a new twiMl app and updating the credentials. I really dont know doesnt make the call